# ./src/Firebase.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React\clones\disney-plus-clone\src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I am working on a react project and I need firebase for authentication I have installed firebase using "npm i firebase" & firebase-tools using "npm i firebase-tools" also the path is correct. There is no problem in defining the path. Everything from my side is correct then also it is showing the above error.

--- Please help -----

Comment: you need to install firebase tools globally  something like -   npm install -g firebase-tools and you must also share code or repo link so I can answer you efficiently

Comment: Bro I have also done that still now same problem

Comment: can you share your code or repo link so I can understand your problem properly?

Comment: https://github.com/Hackish-Web/disney-clone.git

Comment: I have provided 2 files app.js and firebase.js. I have installed the firebase and its in my node_modules but then also why I am unable to start my project from 2 days. It says that firebase module is not found , but I have installed it.....

Comment: I have also provided 3 images for more information. You can see there that I have installed firebase, webpack and the picture of error in cmd ------------Please Help--------------

Comment: I'm working at your problem, please wait for results!

Comment: I have posted results in answer window check out very soon.

Comment: I hope this worked for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why this is happening?**

*If you give a look at firebase package version(inside package.json) then it's version 9. Now firebase has added a new compatibility option so can use the /compat folder in your imports.*

> I have made some changes in Firebase.js file please replace your code
> with the given below and then start your dev server.

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"
import "firebase/compat/storage"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA9BnlX96fMf7XiUVCFRsoQzG8DGERJkeY",
  authDomain: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5",
  storageBucket: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "37918794208",
  appId: "1:37918794208:web:dbe9842dfe1dda522a4b85",
  measurementId: "G-DRVLJKWRWG",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage =firebase.storage();

export { auth,provider,storage};
export default db;
```

Comment: Bro its working . Really brother you solved one of my biggest error still now. I'll be thankful to you. From 2.5 days I was unable to start my project and you did it in a moment. Really you are genius.

Comment: @webdeveloper as a reward for me you can like and accept my answer, it will be a reward, as well as motivation for me and at the last I can say you are always welcome!

Comment: Gulshan Aggarwal You made my day. I am trying to solve this error from 2 days Thank you Man Stay blessed